# Find which event/observer is changing element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am working with Prototype JS framework and I have a form with two select fields (each with three options). There is an observer that changes the text of another element whenever I select a value, which is what it is supposed to do.

However, how do I find out what code is observing that event (the selecting of an option in the form) and therefore making the changes to the element? I've spent the past few hours trying to work it out to no avail.

Am I correct in thinking there is a way to get a stack trace to find out what code is observing that change? Or is there an alternative method to debugging.

Thanks in advance for any advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix was a matter of finding where Event.observe was written in the JavaScript and tracing back.

The documentation was helpful: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Event/observe/